# 500 Server Error: Infinite rewrite loop in Apache 2.2.x with mod_vhost_alias, VirtualDocumentRoot, and mod_rewrite for routing / "pretty" URLs

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm running into a problem using Apache's `mod_vhost_alias` directives and `mod_rewrite` for routing "pretty URLs" with a local development machine. I know that it's possible to do so, because my hosting provider uses a similar configuration and has no problems. However, whenever I try on my local machine, Apache returns a 500 Internal Server Error, and the logs indicate too many internal redirects.

## *Normally* Done

I typically follow a simple conventional process when adding domains to my local machine for development:

- Create a directory in `/path/to/www/` named according to the domain, ie: `/path/to/www/example.local/`
- Add an entry into `/etc/hosts` for the new domain, ie: `127.0.0.1 example.local`
- Add a `VirtualHost` directive for the new domain with the `DocumentRoot` set to `/path/to/www/example.local/pub/`
- Restart Apache

## The Problem

I recently started using the `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive supplied by `mod_vhost_alias` to clean up my ever-growing list of `VirtualHost` directives and save me the hassle of restarting Apache after every new domain:

```
CanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/www/%0/pub/
```

Within one of the domains, say `example.local`, I might have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php/%0 [L]
```

That's a typical "pretty URL" / routing pattern for most modern applications and frameworks. However, Apache enters an infinite redirect loop when I attempt to load `example.local/anything/that/should/work` in my browser.

I enabled the `RewriteLog` to determine what was going on, and found that Apache was performing the following:

- Remove the directory prefix (`/path/to/www/example.local/pub/`) from the URL
- Process the `RewriteRules` normally, as expected, generating `/index.php/anything/that/should/work`
- Prepend the directory prefix again, yielding: `/path/to/www/example.local/pub/index.php/anything/that/should/work`
- Start over. (!?!?)

## The Question

Has anyone else seen this behavior and formulated a fix for it? Alternatively, can someone see a glaring error in my Apache config that I might be missing?

Answer (score 4):

Try using RewriteBase, I had the same problem and it worked for me.
Good luck.

Comment: Also tried adding "RewriteBase /" to some of my RewriteRule blocks with mixed success. It _kinda_ worked but not consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the NS flag to your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/%0 [L,NS]
```

Comment: I haven't. However, as I alluded to above, my hosting provider uses this method to provide domains in a shared environment, and no additional flags are necessary. Thanks for the suggestion, though, and I'll give it a shot.